# Get Title from specific link

Tags: php, meta-tags

I am trying to get the title from an anilink URL. This particular code works for MyAnimeList webiste however on the AniList website this keeps returning 'AniList' which is the website, I believe the website in question is updating the meta tags after loading the webpage using jQuery, however sites like Facebook and discord are able to get the title of a series. However my code can't.

Here is the code I am using.
For example, here is a random URL from the anilist website

https://anilist.co/anime/527/Pocket-Monsters/

```
myfunction(https://anilist.co/anime/527/Pocket-Monsters/)

function myfunction($form_value)
{

$html = file_get_contents_curl($form_value);
 
       //parsing begins here:
         $doc = new DOMDocument();
         @$doc->loadHTML($html);
         $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
   
         //get and display what you need:
         $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
        
         $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
         
        for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
        {
            $meta = $metas->item($i);
            if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:title')
               {$title = $meta->getAttribute('content');}
           if($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:site_name')
              $site_name = $meta->getAttribute('content');
       }


 return $title;
 
 }
```

andi it returns.

```
AniList
```

where as this is the meta tag.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Pokémon" data-vue-meta="true">
```

So i am expecting it to return

```
Pokémon
```

Should i be using another website to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

`Anilist` is the title as given in the page's markup. If you see anything else in your browser, check whether the application overrides the title using Javascript. If this is the case, a pure PHP approach won't help to read the page's final title. You either need to run the whole page in a browser and read the output from there, or use a proper API

Comment: That's what i thought, so how does Discord and Facebook get the title.
If i want to use the 'proper API' what should i be searching for.

Comment: Maybe they run the JS stuff on their servers directly, or they use a proper browser for this (like Chrome in headless-mode)?